# Hyperledger Fabric Multi Org Setup

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How to create/setup our own network with two or more org each having multiple peers in it, and deploy the chaincode on each peer of org in Hyperledger Fabric?
1. how to setup it on the same machine(all Org on the same machine)
2. on a different machine (each org on a separate machine)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Building Your First Network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) tutorial in the Hyperledger Fabric Docs. This provides a working example with 2 organisations, each with 2 peers.

Comment: Yes. but it does not give any information about how to setup the organization on to different machines and connect them.

Comment: I am using byfn and I want to have setup like this : Machine1 : 1-CA, 1-Orderer, 1-Org(Org1) with 2-Peers and On Machine2: 1-Org (Org2) with 2-Peers   
I dont understand how two org will communicate if they are running in two different machine? can anyone help me with communication part?

Comment: As long as each machine has the relevant ports open and is accessible over the network, it's really no different from using containers on the same machine. You can either use the name of the machines in the config (if they are addressable by name) or the IP addresses if not. If you are still having trouble, please post your config files and a detailed summary of your setup.